# how can set Session time out settings in web config file

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, web-config

I want to set session time out in asp.net web config file.I Google it for the best method.then I get multiple results.I am confusing that setting session state following code.which I one choose for appropriate session time out.Can I get a description about it

```
code 1:
<configuration><system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  />
<sessionState timeout="20000"></sessionState>
```

```
code 2:
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2000"/>

code 3:
<sessionState  timeout="40" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`Session timeout` can be set be defining the `timeout` property like this.

```
<sessionState timeout="20000"></sessionState>
```

This time is in `minutes` and default timeout is `20 minutes`.

What is making you confuse is `mode="InProc"`. This is the mode which defines that where session data will be stored there are `different modes` in which data can be saved. Please [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx) this article for details about session state. There are different properties for session state which can be configured just like you have configured `timeout` property.

> Session Modes

**Custom**
Session state is using a custom data store to store session-state information.

**InProc**
Session state is in process with an ASP.NET worker process.

**Off**
Session state is disabled.

**SQLServer**
Session state is using an out-of-process SQL Server database to store state information.

**StateServer**
Session state is using the out-of-process ASP.NET state service to store state information.